# Cmake with Xcode generator. How to add libraries into "Link binary With Libraries" Xcode project section

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake

I can't figure out how to add libraries into "Link binary With Libraries" Xcode project section with cmake. If I do something like `target_link_libraries(MyProject zlib.dylib)` it doesn't make sense on Xcode project when I run `cmake -GXcode ..` as result I have unresolved external symbols but if I add my libraries manually to my target like: `Build Phases -> "+" -> "New Link Binary With Libraries Phase"` In this case I have no linker errors.

macOS 10.14.6, `cmake --version` output: `cmake version 3.15.2`

Comment: you state that doing "something like `target_link_libraries(MyProject zlib.dylib)` it doesn't make sense on Xcode project". This is an obvious error. Pls provide complete working CMakeLists.txt that exhibits the problem you are referring to.

Comment: @gordan.sikic my CMakeLists looks like this 

`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14). 

project(MyProject). 

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14). 

add_executable(MyProject main.cpp). 

target_include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/zlib). 

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/zlib). 

target_link_libraries(MyProject -lz)`